# Pandas merge 5 csv files with only 1 different column name

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I have 5 csv files which I'm trying to merge using Python Pandas, also I'm running 64-bit Python cause of Memory issue.

All 5 csv files have identical column names:
`['A', 'B', 'C', ... 'Start_time', 'end_time', 'Unique_column']`

Here **Unique_column** is the different column name per CSV file. So I need to merge all 5 files with each other, so in the end I will get DataFrame as

`['A', 'B', 'C', ... 'Start_time', 'end_time', 'Unique_column1', 'Unique_colum2', ... 'Unique_colum5']`

Is it `pandas.merge` or `pandas.concat` method?

**UPDATE**:

```
>>> import os
>>> import glob
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dir_name = r'C:\Users\data'
>>> dfs = []
>>> files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_name, '*.csv'))
>>> for f in files:
...   df = pd.read_csv(f)
...   dfs.append(df)
...
>>> common_cols = ['Target', 'POS', 'Start_Week', 'End_Week', 'Measure_Metric']
>>> res = pd.concat([df.set_index(common_cols) for df in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 846, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "c:\Python27x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1031, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.reindex(new_labels)[1]
  File "c:\Python27x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\multi.py", line 1422, in reindex
    raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `pd.concat` after having set the index on each to be all common columns.

Imagine you have all files imported into the list `dfs`

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
```

Then concat like

```
common_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Start_time', 'end_time']
pd.concat([df.set_index(common_cols) for df in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Getting this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 846, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "c:\Python27x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 1031, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.reindex(new_labels)[1]
  File "c:\Python27x64\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\multi.py", line 1422, in reindex
    raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
df_master['unique1'] = df_reference1['unique1']
```

this will create the new row 'unique1'.  Watch your indexing!

Comment: I set up indexes on common columns, e.g. all columns that appear in all CSV files.

output of this actually looks good, but for example, if the biggest CSV file has 20M rows, then in output file, it has about 10K -- but this understandable that most of rows didn't match. But I just manually checked out - and not sure if results make sense... Will try to sort files first